# Can Springboot config server publish anything other than properties and yml file

Tags: java, spring, configserver

Config server has made it easy to use properties from properties file. Is there a way we can use different kind of files like certificates in config client app? Or is there a springboot way of having certificates in some other external git location and make it available in consuming app like config server do it.

Comment: AFAIK, a Spring *Cloud* config server can only send the aforementioned types of file. *However*, you might send the location of a certificate file and have the application retrieve this file.

Comment: Reading more about config server and looks like it can display simple text too... https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_serving_plain_text. Will keep reading , as setting path (i assume git only) and get from that git path will not simple.. i think